# Cumsum on one column conditional on number of occurence of values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, vectorization, tidyverse

The title really is just a very rough idea and very likely not a good match for the actual problem.

I have some stock data, which looks likes this:

```
"DateTime","Price","Volume","Group"
2020-05-01 13:30:01.354,174.003,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:01.454,174.003,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:01.612,174.592,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:01.663,174.812,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:01.775,174.742,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.090,174.742,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.139,174.742,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.190,174.743,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.308,174.612,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.428,174.612,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.554,174.522,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.656,174.552,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.705,174.522,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.913,174.645,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:02.963,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:03.013,175.002,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:03.125,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:03.312,174.803,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:03.362,175.002,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:03.876,174.772,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:03.927,174.802,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.052,174.802,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.154,174.692,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.203,174.802,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.255,174.803,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.304,174.803,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.404,174.802,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.455,175.003,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.521,174.803,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.649,174.802,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.771,174.803,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.822,174.803,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.899,174.702,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:04.950,174.802,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:06.498,174.722,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:07.794,174.723,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:07.843,175.003,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:08.095,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:08.466,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:08.567,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:08.743,174.982,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:09.123,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:09.381,174.982,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:09.893,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:09.942,174.882,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:09.993,174.962,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:11.404,175.002,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:11.716,174.963,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:11.932,174.963,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:11.983,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:12.038,174.962,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:12.414,174.963,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:12.533,174.863,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:12.585,174.962,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:13.763,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:14.473,174.962,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:16.157,174.962,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:16.207,175.002,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:16.268,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:18.455,175.002,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:18.506,175.322,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:19.289,175.322,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:19.340,175.342,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:19.953,175.343,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:20.761,175.362,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:21.588,175.363,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:21.638,175.382,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:22.387,175.383,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:22.486,175.442,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:22.580,175.382,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:23.595,175.442,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:23.645,175.383,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:23.762,175.442,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:24.085,175.382,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:24.134,175.273,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:24.608,175.272,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:24.658,175.272,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.019,175.272,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.070,175.332,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.238,175.283,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.289,175.282,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.749,175.273,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.799,175.273,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.863,175.273,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:25.914,175.333,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:26.073,175.283,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:26.124,175.282,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:26.187,175.203,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:26.237,175.182,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:26.710,175.282,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:27.511,175.282,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:27.763,175.332,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.187,175.233,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.236,175.232,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.302,175.232,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.353,175.232,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.457,175.152,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.507,175.152,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.601,175.153,2000.0001,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.894,175.093,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:28.945,175.092,750,2020-05-01
2020-05-01 13:30:29.049,175.093,2000.0001,2020-05-01
```

What I wanted to do was to calculate a `cumsum` for `Volume` based on the sequential frequencies of values in `Price` column. Following is an example `r` output of above `csv` as `data.frame/data.table`.

```
                  DateTime   Price Volume      Group
 1: 2020-05-01 13:30:01.354 174.003    750 2020-05-01
 2: 2020-05-01 13:30:01.454 174.003    750 2020-05-01
 3: 2020-05-01 13:30:01.612 174.592    750 2020-05-01
 4: 2020-05-01 13:30:01.663 174.812    750 2020-05-01
 5: 2020-05-01 13:30:01.775 174.742    750 2020-05-01
 6: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.090 174.742   2000 2020-05-01
 7: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.139 174.742    750 2020-05-01
 8: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.190 174.743   2000 2020-05-01
 9: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.308 174.612   2000 2020-05-01
10: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.428 174.612    750 2020-05-01
 8: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.554 174.522   2000 2020-05-01
 9: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.656 174.552   2000 2020-05-01
10: 2020-05-01 13:30:02.705 174.522    750 2020-05-01
```

To explain in more details, I'll take first 2 rows and sum up their corresponding volumes into one element of an output data object (preferably `data.frame`); the prices of row 3 and row 4 have a frequency of 1 (unique occurrence in the price series) therefore their volumes do not need to be summed up and would produce 2 rows in output data object. price for row 5,6,7 was the same 174.742, then again I'd sum up 3 volumes and produce 1 row in output data object. The same logic applies to the rest of the data.

I've been experimenting with `dplyr` but to no avail; the best I could get was the index groups for each price occurrence but the natural order could not be reserved.  I can't think of a way to even get close to the result I wanted (in a vectorised flavour I was trying to avoid plain looping and writing too much logic).

as suggested by @RonakShah I'll add this expected output example. Sorry I didn't add one earlier as I really wasn't sure what it would look like. But as I thought over once again, I think I would just need an output for the `cumsum` volume sequence, as a single column. I don't really need another column for indexing (although apparently any additional column would serve as very-nice-to-have).

Example output:

```
         Cumsum.Volume
    1:       1500  # aggregated from row 1,2 as they have same price
    2:       750   # no aggregation as row 3 has occurred only once
    3:       750   # same as above
    4:       3500  # aggregation from row 4,5,6 as they have the same price
    5:       2000  # row 7 no aggregation for unique price occurrence in sequence
    6:       2750  # row 8,9 maps to same price so add them up
    7:       2000  # row 10 needs no aggregation
    8:       2000  # row 11 needs no aggregation
    9:       750   # row 12 needs no aggregation
```

Here's a mapping between price and volume:

```
`174.003` appeared twice together, so we cumsum their volumes
`174.592` appeared by itself, so we keep its volume
`174.812` appeared by itself, so we keep its volume
`174.742` appeared 3 times consecutively, so we cumsum/aggregate their volumes
`174.743` appeared by itself, so we keep its volume
`174.612` appeared twice together, so we cumsum their volumes
`174.522` appeared once by itself, we keep its volume
`174.552` appeared by itself, we keep its volume
`174,522` appeared again by itself, we keep its volume
```

I hope above addition could give you guys a better idea; the order of the `cumsum` volume was in correspondence with the natural order of the price column, but I don't need to keep the price column.

Any tips for a right direction?

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(Price) %>%  mutate(Volume  = cumsum(Volume))` ? Can you show first few line of expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah sorry I just got back; I think I don't need the grouping for price as I wanted to keep the original order of the price sequence (actually I think I can disregard the price sequence all together, I just need to create a new column of cumsum volumes using the price sequence) I'll try to add an example of expected output (I didn't add as it was a bit too tedious to create by hand and not so sure what it should look like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ronak Shah says, you might just want to group by price then take the cumulative sum of the volume. However, you need to be careful, because if you just group by price, you will inadvertantly group some later rows with earlier rows (say, if the price goes up then falls back to the same place later on). I'm guessing you don't want this. Therefore you should group according to adjacent rows with the same price. You can do that like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(PriceChange = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Price) != 0))) %>%
  group_by(PriceChange) %>%
  mutate(CumSumVolume = cumsum(Volume)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-PriceChange) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

The first few rows of output would look like this:

```
#>                    DateTime   Price Volume      Group CumSumVolume
#> 1   2020-05-01 13:30:01.354 174.003    750 2020-05-01          750
#> 2   2020-05-01 13:30:01.454 174.003    750 2020-05-01         1500
#> 3   2020-05-01 13:30:01.612 174.592    750 2020-05-01          750
#> 4   2020-05-01 13:30:01.663 174.812    750 2020-05-01          750
#> 5   2020-05-01 13:30:01.775 174.742    750 2020-05-01          750
#> 6   2020-05-01 13:30:02.090 174.742   2000 2020-05-01         2750
#> 7   2020-05-01 13:30:02.139 174.742    750 2020-05-01         3500
#> 8   2020-05-01 13:30:02.190 174.743   2000 2020-05-01         2000
#> 9   2020-05-01 13:30:02.308 174.612   2000 2020-05-01         2000
#> 10  2020-05-01 13:30:02.428 174.612    750 2020-05-01         2750
#> 11  2020-05-01 13:30:02.554 174.522   2000 2020-05-01         2000
#> 12  2020-05-01 13:30:02.656 174.552    750 2020-05-01          750
#> 13  2020-05-01 13:30:02.705 174.583   2000 2020-05-01         2000
```

Comment: you are very right; I did have that situation in mind; your grouping is how I wanted. i.e. the original order of price sequence is reserved in the output. Thanks for a very neat answer.

Comment: your answer is giving me what I wanted with just a few more steps (the accumulation process which I can live without), is there a way we could single out just the final number (for the adjacent rows that have same price) ? I tried changing `cumsum` to `sum` but this created duplicates that I can't safely remove (I don't if it is just a sum or not)..

Comment: @stucash yes. Instead of `mutate(CumSumVolume = cumsum(Volume))` you do `summarise(DateTime = min(DateTime), Volume = sum(Volume))`

Comment: Thanks Allan; it worked. One more question for `c(TRUE, diff(Price)!=0)`, I tried `diff(Price)!=0`, it produced an identical output, did I miss something here? what does this expression do here?

Answer (score 1):

Group by the date part of `DateTime` and by `Price`

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
          DateTime=ymd_hms(c("2020-05-01 13:30:01.354", "2020-05-01 13:30:01.454", "2020-05-01 13:30:01.612", 
                                        "2020-05-01 13:30:01.663", "2020-05-01 13:30:01.775", "2020-05-01 13:30:02.090", 
                                        "2020-05-01 13:30:02.139", "2020-05-01 13:30:02.190", "2020-05-01 13:30:02.308", 
                                        "2020-05-01 13:30:02.428")),

          Price=c(174.003, 174.003, 174.592, 174.812, 174.742, 174.742, 174.742, 174.743, 174.612, 174.612),
          Volume=c(750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 2000, 750, 2000, 2000, 750))

groupedData <- data %>%
  mutate(Date=lubridate::as_date(DateTime)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Price) %>% 
  summarise(Volume=sum(Volume)) %>% 
  ungroup()

groupedData
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Date       Price Volume
  <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2020-05-01  174.   1500
2 2020-05-01  175.    750
3 2020-05-01  175.   2750
4 2020-05-01  175.   3500
5 2020-05-01  175.   2000
6 2020-05-01  175.    750
```

Comment: I think either @Allan Cameron or I could be correct depending on whether or not crossing midnight automatically triggers a new group.  I don't think we have that information in your question.

Comment: great answer! It's almost as I wanted if we could reserve the original order of the price column. i.e. it'd be .003 -> .592 -> .812 -> .742 -> .742 -> .612. I think `summarise` is doing the implicit sorting here.

Comment: there's typo in my comment above; it should be .742 -> .743

Comment: It seems `group_by()` does indeed sort.  Sometimes.  ((See here)[https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3279].)  I didn't know that.  I see you prefer @Alan Cameron's solution as it doesn't start a new group if a sequence crosses midnight, so I won't spend time on a work around.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort @Limey Allan’s answer with a small tweak does give me what I wanted right there and then; yours would as well with your update but I've got what I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: Also I just tried this as a simple test: `data %>% group_by(Date,Price)`, the order seemed preserved; but if I go further and add `%>% summarise(Volume=sum(Volume))`, the output was sorted. I noticed the `group_by` problem on github, but not sure if this is due to `group_by`?

Comment: It seems that `group_by()` does sort, but only sometimes, in the interests of efficiency.  That's my take on the github thread that I linked to above (very ineptly!).  I wasn't aware of that before.  99% of the time, it doesn't matter, because you want to present the sorted  summary anyway.  Your ecxample is one of the 1%.  On reflection, the mod to my solution would make it so close to @Alan Cameron's that you'd be hard pressed to spot the difference.